# When does a non-dynamic variable goes out of scope if being referenced by a pointer?

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ programming and I am having some hard time understanding some concepts.

Take this code as a example:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>

class nber
{
    int* value;
    
  public:  
  nber(int n)
  {
      value = &n;
  }
  int getNber()
  {
      return *value;
  }
};

int main()
{
  nber var(111);
  std::cout << "The number is:" << var.getNber() << "\n";
}
```

As you can see, the nber constructor receives an integer n and passes its address to the "value" pointer. What I expected is to have some kind of unwanted behavior, since the scope of the received integer (n) ends as soon as the constructor end, but the output is:

> The number is:111

So the scope didn't end? If it really didn't end, when is the memory used to store the variable n going to be released? Thanks.

Comment: *Values* go out of scope at their matching closing brace. You have a reference to a temporary, so this is undefined behavior. *Pointers* may be *dangling* in that they reference memory that has gone out of scope. It's up to us the programmers to make sure that doesn't happen. C++ will let you shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: Welcome to undefined behavior land, where anything can happen.

Comment: You do have unwanted behaviour. The behaviour of the program is undefined. Your compiler is being most unkind to you in this case by making the program appear to work.

Comment: So the best solution would be to use a "malloc" in this case or a "new" in case of an object?

Comment: Typically you want to pass and store and return value when possible.  Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Will take a look. Thanks everyone for the help :)

Comment: using `new` is rarely the best solution and `malloc` almost never

Comment: Try adding some other function calls after `nber var(111);`. Like maybe `nber var(111); cout << "hello world!\n"; cout << var.getNber();`

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scope *did* end. What you're seeing is Undefined Behavior - anything can happen. The number could be "purple", as far as the rules say. Or your hard disk could be erased. The latter is a bit rare, though.

Comment: I would go and look at eric's answer he has a popular answer about undefined behavior: It basically uses a hotel room analogy, if you have an unsafe hotel, and you did not return back their key and decided to come back later to get your items, the item may be there, or the hotel may be demolished or the book might be taken, since it is undefined anything can happen....